# How do I setup lenskit recommender toolkit to run in a website?

Tags: java, maven, lenskit

I'm using lenskit recommender toolkit in Netbeans 7.4 to build a movie recommendation engine and now I'm finalizing it. So my question is how will I be able to integrate it into Web to build a Movie Recommendation Website?
I've already visit the GitHub getting started site for lenskit [here](https://github.com/grouplens/lenskit/wiki/GettingStarted) and I've found the keyword web integration, click that but nothing helped me.
Sorry for the vague question but can you help me or give some advice on how to start? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main things you need to do:

1. Create a `RecommenderEngine` containing your model, configuration, etc.  This will be a global object shared between all web requests.  You can also build it in a separate program, serialize it to disk, and read it back in.
2. In each web request, use the `createRecommender()` method to get a `Recommender` for that request to use.

You'll need to handle data access; there is some documentation on that here: https://github.com/grouplens/lenskit/wiki/DataAccess

LensKit 2.0 was a bit weak on web integration; LensKit 2.1 makes it significantly easier.  Look for a 2.1 milestone release very soon.

Comment: Okay, thank you for giving me the idea. Now I'm creating the `RecommenderEngine` as you said. Now I'm playing with the `HelloLenskit` in the demo project provided. It is now up and running but how can I get the movie title base on the movie ID provided? In `ratings.dat` it only provides the ID's, so how will I be able to load the `movies.dat` to search on the movie title?

Comment: @Harvey LensKit doesn't have direct support for doing anything with `movies.dat`, as it doesn't need it (routing plumbing for data that LensKit doesn't need increases the burden of integrating it into different environments). However, you can use `DelimitedTextCursor` from LensKit to ease parsing it yourself.