# Is there some way to use Lenskit as recommender engine and call him from Django/Python?

Tags: java, python, django, recommendation-engine, lenskit

So my question is how will I be able to integrate it into Web, especialy a Django site? I know that there is PredictionIO (http://prediction.io/) that includes a Python SDK. Is there something like this for Lenskit?

I knew about Lenskit at the coursera course about Recommender Systems: https://www.coursera.org/course/recsys and i'm seeing the classes, including the one about Lenskit. I saw the documentation on the github too: https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit/wiki/GettingStarted but it's not clear to me how to integrate it into the website.

For example, with predictionio, there is this example: http://docs.prediction.io/current/tutorials/quickstart-python.html so you can use PredictionIO as a service. Is there something like this for Lenskit?

I saw this question too: [How do I setup lenskit recommender toolkit to run in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994926/how-do-i-setup-lenskit-recommender-toolkit-to-run-in-a-website)

BUT, as i can see, is about calling it from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call LensKit from Python (or PHP, or Ruby), you will need to set up LensKit as a web service, exposing a REST API that your Python code can call.

There is a [work-in-progress example web service](https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit-webservice), but it still needs to be updated to the latest version of LensKit and documented. So right now, there is not an out-of-the-box solution for using LensKit from Python.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Extra question: is there some prediction about when your course (Recommender Systems) will be offered again?

Comment: @FlavioBarros We're in discussion about when/how to do that. Hopefully in the spring.

Comment: @FlavioBarros the Coursera recsys course is now available year-round with certificates available: https://www.coursera.org/learn/recommender-systems

Comment: Hello. I just started taking the coursera class.. wonder if there's an update for the same question.